# How do I apply housewrap to an existing structure when reducing an opening size?

Tags: doors, exterior, siding

We have a fairly wide (96'' sliding glass door which we would like install a smaller one).  This obviously means we need to reduce the rough opening.

The part I can't seem to find information is how do I tie in "new" house wrap for the new exterior due to the reduction in size of the rough opening.  After I put on OSB to the new studs how would I wrap that to the existing home?

Any guidance?

Comment: House wrap tape?

Comment: Joints in house wrap are lapped properly for drainage and taped, just as with new construction. End of story. Is there something about your framing or siding situation that confounds you? Please revise to add clarity about your concern. Also take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove existing door
- Remove some siding from around (including above) the existing door frame
- Build new, smaller opening (adjust the header as necessary)
- Apply new sheathing to new construction
- Apply new house wrap to new construction, overlapping house wrap on existing construction
- Apply tape to new house wrap seam to hold it to existing house wrap
- Install door, trim and new siding